# Can ActiveRecord be setup to automatically limit second degree associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Let's say I have a `User` model which `has_many :posts`, while `Post` `has_many :comments`.

If I do `@user.posts.map {|post| post.comments}.flatten` I'll get *all* the comments on the user's posts. Is there somewhere to configure the `Post` or `Comment` model to detect it's being referenced in the context of a specific user and only return the specific user's comments?

That is, `@user.posts.map {|post| post.comments}.flatten` and `@posts.map {|post| post.comments}.flatten` (assuming the same posts) wouldn't return the same number of comments (assuming multiple users are commenting).

From a [previous SO question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778241/complex-associations-in-activerecord-models), it sounds like I want some sort of [nested has_many through](https://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through). Is that correct? Is there any easy way in Rails 3 to detect the 'source'?

Comment: Not sure I follow. It sounds like you want to find a specific user's comments, right? If so, you should link a user and his/her comments directly: i.e. `User` `has_many :comments`. No need for complex nesting of relations.

Comment: Correct, but I want them in the context of the posts.

Comment: So you want the user's comments to his/her own posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer:

Here's a method that'll get a post's author's comments

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user   # So, there's a user_id attribute
  has_many :comments

  def authors_comments
    comments.where("user_id = ?", user_id)
  end
end
```

That should let you do:

```
@user.posts.each { |post| puts post, post.authors_comments }
```

it's not as efficient as the other method, though; *n* posts will result in *n* SQL queries to get the comments. But it's pretty close to what was described in the comment below.

---

*Original answer (for posterity)*

It ain't the prettiest, but you can do something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts    # All the user's posts
  has_many :comments # All the user's comments on all posts

  # All comments made on any of user's posts
  has_many :replies, :through => :posts, :source => :comments

  def replies_to_self
    replies.where("comments.user_id = ?", id)
  end
end
```

Call `@user.replies_to_self` to get the users' comments to his/her own posts

You end up with SQL like this:

```
SELECT
    "comments".*
FROM
    "comments"
INNER JOIN
    "posts"
ON
    "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id"
WHERE
    "posts"."user_id" = X AND "comments"."user_id" = X
```

(where `X` would be the user's id)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't address what I'm looking for: from the user being able to reference the posts and then inside of the posts be able to get just the user's comments. Think something like `@user.posts.each {|post| puts post, post.my_comments }`

Comment: @pr1001 Updated my answer. Still don't know if it's what you're looking for exactly, but between the two answers you should be able to find a way of doing what you want, I hope